# _Visualforce.Ajax.timeout meaning exactly?

Tags: timeout, javascript-remoting

I see there is a

```
_Visualforce.Ajax.timeout
```

attribute that can be set for JS remoting. See ref [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gLukAAE)

I am wondering what is being timed here. The server side time? The client round trip time?

What happens when the timeout is reached client side?  I can't simulate it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the round-trip time (the time it takes to receive a response back from the server after sending a JavaScript remoting request). When the timeout is reached, the request is abandoned and an error message is returned.

Here's the [release notes for this functionality](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf) (see page 209 and after or the copied text below).

> ## Configurable Timeout for JavaScript Remoting Requests
>
> You asked for it! This enhancement is from an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gLukAAE) on the IdeaExchange.
>   In Summer ’13 the timeout period for JavaScript remoting requests is configurable. In prior releases, the timeout was fixed at
>   30 seconds, and this remains the default. If your request needs longer to complete, configure a longer timeout, up to 120
>   seconds.
>
> ### Configuring JavaScript Remoting Requests
>
> Configure a remoting request by providing an object with configuration settings when you declare the remoting request. For example, the default configuration parameters look like this:
>
> ```
> { buffer: true, escape: true, timeout: 30000 }
> ```
>
> These configuration parameters aren’t ordered, and you can omit parameters you don’t want to change from the default.
>   JavaScript remoting supports the following configuration parameters:
>
> ```
> Name    Data Type   Description
> ---------------------------------------------------------------
> buffer  Boolean     Whether to group requests executed close to 
>                     each other in time into a single request. The default is true. 
>
>                     JavaScript remoting optimizes requests that are executed close 
>                     to each other in time and groups the calls into a single request. 
>                     This buffering improve the efficiency of the overall 
>                     request-and-response cycle, but sometimes it’s useful to ensure 
>                     all requests execute independently.
>
> escape  Boolean     Whether to escape the Apex method’s response. The default is true.
>
> timeout Integer     The timeout for the request, in milliseconds. 
>                     The default is 30000 (30 seconds). The maximum is 120000 
>                     (120 seconds, or 2 minutes).
> ```
>
> The request timeout can also be configured for all requests made by a page, by setting the timeout using the Visualforce remoting object:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   Visualforce.remoting.timeout = 120000; // Set timeout at page level
>
>   function getRemoteAccount() {
>     var accountName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;
>
>     // This remoting call will use the page's timeout value
>     Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
>       '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}',
>       accountName,
>       handleResult
>     );
>   }
>
>   function handleResult(result, event) { ... }
> </script>
> ```
>
> Override a page-level timeout configuration on a per-request basis by setting the timeout in the configuration object for that request, as described above.

Comment: By default, the response of the remote call must return within 30 seconds, after which the call will time out. If your request needs longer to complete, configure a longer timeout, up to 120 seconds.

Comment: Prior comment is from JavaScript Remoting for Apex Controllers page. I take this to mean that the server must start responding within the timeout period (so, open socket time plus server processing time), which is the usual definition of a network timeout.